# Finding the desired sum in a row of a 2d array java

Tags: java, multidimensional-array

I'm having trouble wrapping my head around how to implement a method that starts with an int[][] input and a predefined sum value that returns an int[][] output that only displays the adjacent values in the row that add up to the sum. For example, if the input array was

```
int[][] input = new int[][]{
{3,4,4,2,7},
{2,3,2,8,6},
{1,4,2,1,2}
}
```

when the sum is set to 7, it would yield an output array with the following values

```
{3,4,0,0,7},
{2,3,2,0,0},
{1,4,2,1,0}
}
```

The output array should only display values that add up to a set number (7) with their neighbors, or if its a number from 0-9 values that are the desired sum (when you search for 7 it displays all 7s). To further clarify, as you can see in the output array, it displays the first two values, 3 and 4, because they add to 7. It displays 2,3,2 because they also add to 7. It prints out 1,4,2,1 on the bottom because 1,4,2 add to 7 and 4,2,1 add to 7. To summarize, it displays only values which are 7 or add up to 7 with the numbers next to them, and otherwise displays 0. Also the input values must be <0.

After brainstorming for a while I know that the code will need a number of nested loops: one to loop through the rows, inside that one to loop through the columns, inside that a loop to update the sum which stops when the sum equals the preset sum (7 in this case), and finally a loop to update the output[][]. However, I'm having a great deal of trouble on writing code that implements all of these loops correctly. I am planning on doing the same thing with numbers that add up vertically, but want to focus on horizontal as of now.

Comment: When you display `{1,4,2,1,0}` for the last row, is it because 1 + 4 + 2 = 7 *and* 4 + 2 + 1 = 7? Then it’s not so bad.

Comment: Yes, if a number is part of a string of numbers that adds up to the sum, it displays that number.

Answer (score 0):

You need three nested loops. Or really, three levels of nested loops with two loops after each other on the innermost level, but I will return to that in the end.

Before any loops, create the backbone of your result array. It’s OK if it’s an array of null references to arrays at this point.

Outer loop: loop through the outer array. A classical `for` loop is one option. For each entry, create an inner array of the correct length in the result, filled with zeroes for a start.

Middle loop, loop through the entries in the inner array. Again a classical `for` loop is fine. Your goal is that each iteration will determine if a series of adjacent values with the sum 7 begins at this entry, and if so, find out how long it is, and copy the entries in question to the result array.

Inner loop (first inner loop, that is) is for adding adjacent entries to find out if the sum is 7. You start from the entry from the middle loop and add up the values. This loop has a double stop condition: you stop when the sum is 7 or greater (assuming all values are positive), but obviously you also stop when reaching the end of the inner array. A `while` loop would be for my taste. Only if the sum hits exactly 7, do you use a new inner loop to copy the values to the result.

PS If you assume all values are positive, you shouldn’t just assume, you should check. In the middle loop, if the value in that entry is 0 or negative, throw an `IllegalArgumentException`.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response, I'll try to implement it later today and I'll get back!

Answer (score 0):

This can be done in O(NxM) complexity.

For each row, you keep two indexes (say, iLow and iHigh initialised to the first item input [i][0]) and a sumSoFar variable. At each iteration, if the sumSoFar < 7 you increment iHigh. If it is > 7 then you increment iLow and iHigh. If It is == 7 then you've found one combination + increment iLow and iHigh.

This should give the high-level idea of the algorithm and I'm sure that a lot of details are missing/incomplete but you should be able to put that in code.

Comment: Clever. Still provided all numbers in the array are positive (> 0).